# How to change the color of a slicing area using onMouseOver and onmouseout using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I have sliced an image and devided the image in different images. 
I have posted a dummy  image for better understanding the left side image is present state and i am expecting the output as the right side image.
I want to change the color of that slice image on mouseover and 
onmouseout event,and also want to use onMouseDown event for other purpose for that image.

[image]

Below is my code:-

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <style>
        aaa:hover {
            color:red;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <script>
            var sundarg;
            sundarg =   document.getElementById('sundarg');

            function mouseinaa()
            {
                sundarg.style.display="#FF0000";
            }

            function mouseoutaa()
            {
                sundarg.style.display="#FFFFFF";
            }   
        </script>
        <img src="image/map3.png" usemap="#Map" />
        <map name="Map">

        <area shape="poly"  id="sundarg" coords="226,75,228,70,228,65,228,61,229,57,232,52,234,49,239,46,243,45,246,43,248,41,252,39,254,39,256,38,259,36,260,36,260,34,261,32,259,30,258,29,258,26,257,25,260,25,261,25,263,26,265,28,266,29,266,31,267,32,268,35,269,36,271,37,272,37,276,39,283,40,284,40,282,39,284,38,288,37,292,37,292,36,296,34,299,34,302,33,305,33,308,32,310,33,312,33,314,32,317,32,320,31,322,31,326,30,328,31,329,31,330,33,331,35,331,38,331,39,332,42,331,49,330,50,325,55,322,56,327,56,330,55,332,56,334,58,336,58,338,59,340,60,340,61,341,63,342,65,342,67,342,67,344,67,345,67,347,67,348,68,350,70,351,73,347,74,341,74,340,76,340,79,337,83,339,87,337,91,335,91,333,90,326,87,318,86,313,85,311,85,309,84,301,81,298,79,296,78,295,76,293,73,293,70,293,68,294,65,294,64,293,60,293,58,293,56,293,55,291,53,290,52,287,50,286,50,282,50,280,53,278,54,276,55,276,57,275,58,275,60,275,62,274,61,270,63,268,63,266,62,264,62,261,63,258,65,256,66,254,65,251,63,244,66,248,67,246,69,243,71,241,72,238,74,237,75,234,75,232,76,231,76,226,76,225,76,227,74,259,53,228,73,229,72" onMouseOver="mouseinaa()" onmouseout="mouseoutaa()" >
        </map>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you reproduce this in a http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: @ThoughtfulThighentist thanks ,could you please tell me,How to use this link, Is this site enable to upload an image for slicing ?

Comment: No, JsFiddle is a site where you can post your sample code and let others try it while trying to help you improve your code